# Topological definition of continuity for undefined points in the domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose we are given a piecewise function $f: \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$.

This function will be continuous everywhere in "real analysis sense" (using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition) and in "topological sense" (using the standard topology and continuity defined there) because we excluded $ \{ 0 \}$ in the domain.

However, if we insist on including $\{ 0 \}$ in its domain, i.e. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This function will not be continuous everywhere in "real analysis sense" because it is undefined at $0$ in the first place. Since continuity in "topological sense" is equivalent to continuity in "real analysis sense", this function, with $0$ in the domain but undefined there, should also not be continuous in "topological sense".

My question is which among the subsets in the standard topology in the codomain does not have an open pre-image for this to be considered non-continuous in "topological sense"?

Comment: It does not make sense to have the value of a function undefined in any point in the domain.

Comment: If you “insist on including $0$” then the function is no longer a function. It may seem like $X=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is missing a point, but the topology is homeomorphic to (topologically equivalent to) $\mathbb R\times\{1,2\}.$ From that point of view, the space is not obviously “missing a point.” So you only notice that “missing point” because you have a narrow view of the space $X$ that only considers it as a subspace of a particular parent set.

Comment: You can give an argument that the function is not continuously extendable at $0$, as I did. It's the only way it can make sense.

Comment: An amusing fact is that $X=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y=\mathbb R\setminus[-1,1].$ So, as a space, are you missing a point or an interval? If you extend $f$ from $Y$ to the whole real line, you can make $f$ still continuous.

Comment: Oh I already get it. I just had a little confusion in the definition of a function. Where I assumed that a function should give at most one value for everything in the domain. But it should also give at least one value, so a function cannot be undefined somewhere in the domain. That's why we cannot insist on putting 0 in the domain without defining it. And defining it will make it discontinuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assign some value $f(0) =c$ for a $c \in \Bbb R$, then whatever $c$ is, the result will *not* be continuous with domain $\Bbb R$: for any neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, $f[U] = \{1,0,c\}$ and this can never lie entirely inside a neighbourhood of $f(0)$. (or, we could use that $f[U]$ should be connected for a continuous $f$, because $\Bbb R$ has a base of connected neighbourhoods). And as to preimages, take any open set in the codomain that includes $c$ but not $1$ or $0$, if $c \neq 0,1$, and then $f^{-1}[U]=\{0\}$ is not open. Or if $c=0$ we take $U= (-\frac12, \frac12)$ and then $f^{-1}[U] = (-\infty,0]$ which is not open ($0$ is not interior) or when $c=1$ we take $U=(\frac12,+\infty)$ which has $f^{-1}[U] = [0,+\infty)$, also not open. The local argument with connectedness works better IMHO.